# How to find data from two collections in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

For the first time, I am using MongoDB for my project. I want to get data from two collections and want to sort them by their price. Let's say there are 2 collections - buy and sell. **Buy** product collection is as below:

```
{
    name: "buy 1",
    price: 20
},
{
    name: "buy 2",
    prce: 40
}
```

And **sell** product collection is as below

```
{
    name: "sell 1",
    price: 15
},
{
    name: "sell 2",
    prce: 32
}
```

I want to write an query, which will return following result:

```
{
    name: "sell 1",
    price: 15
},
{
    name: "buy 1",
    price: 20
},
{
    name: "sell 2",
    prce: 32
},
{
    name: "buy 2",
    prce: 40
}
```

How to do it? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I do not believe that it is possible with a single query to extract data from more than one collection. Queries themselves are executed on a per collection basis: `db.collection.find()`. My suggestion would be to make two queries and then merge & sort the data at the application level.

Comment: Depending on your situation, your data, and the queries you are wanting to execute - it might make sense to merge these two collections into one `products` collection and then quantify `buy/sell` with a `type` attribute. This way you would be able to fetch only the `{ 'type': 'buy' }` documents or only the `{ 'type': 'sell' }` documents - and of course, it would allow you to extract (and sort) both types of products in one query.

Comment: as long as there is no common value in both collections there is no way to link them. `Union All` is not an option in mongo

Comment: @Lix you can get data from more than one collection as long as you have common field like `col1.id == col2.parentId`

Comment: @profesor79 - I'm not familiar with that approach - what would a query like that look like?

Comment: @Lix see [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in aggregation framework

Comment: @profesor79 - ahhhh I see, I see. I haven't really played with the aggregation framework - looks like interesting stuff! Thanks for the insights!

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I think then I should merge buy and sell collections into one collection.

Comment: @PrachiSharma - that might be the best solution in this case. I recommend that you take a few moments to consider what other types of queries you are interested in executing. Once you know how you wish to query the data, you'll be able to make better decisions with regard to the structure of your DB and data.